# Implementing Adversarial Training in TensorFlow

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I would like to implement the following cost function for my neural network:
[image]

This makes use of adversarial inputs for the neural network to improve generalization [[ref]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6572.pdf).

Specifically, I am having trouble with the
[image] part.
In my TensorFlow graph, I have defined [image] as an operation. How can I feed [image] with an argument other than [image]?

The only way I have found to do this so far is to define a parallel network [image] that shares the weights with my original network and passing it [image] in its `feed_dict` argument. If possible, I would like to avoid having to redefine my entire network. How can I do this?

---

My TensorFlow model is written as:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32, 32]);
... # A simple neural network
y = tf.add(tf.matmul(h, W1), b1);
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, t));
```

---

Possibly relevant:

> ### tf.stop_gradient(input, name=None)
>
> Stops gradient computation.
>
> *...lots more stuff...*
>
> - Adversarial training, where no backprop should happen through the adversarial example generation process.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#stop_gradient

Comment: How did you write your model code? Do you have a method of a model class that builds the fprop graph given some tensor? Or are you using some existing code released along with TensorFlow?

Comment: Updated original question to reflect the definition of the model.

Comment: @Shadowen, I need to do the same, can you share your code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to write your model in such a way that it supports calls like

```
output = model.fprop(input_tensor)
```

or

```
output = model.fprop(input_tensor, params)
```

The fprop method builds the same forward propagation expression twice, but with a different input tensor on each call:

```
raw_output = model.fprop(clean_examples)
adv_examples = ...
adv_output = model.fprop(adv_examples)
```

If you want to apply this to one of our open source models and it doesn't support the interface to do this, file an issue on github.

Comment: So after a bit more reading, I found that in
[this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py), the model-builder was extracted to a function, which basically allows the model to be built many times (almost identically). Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, create a function (or method for a model class) that builds the fprop graph given an input tensor. Then call the function on a placeholder or whatever tensor is appropriate.

Comment: Ok, so this does require building "two networks" on the TensorFlow computation graph. I assume this is necessary because for each pass through the computation graph, each Tensor may only have one value (so that TensorFlow can perform backpropogation, etc)?